# Finding all rational solutions of $~y^2 = -x(4x^2 - 9x + 4)~$

Tags: diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

Finding all rational solutions of $$y^2 = -x(4x^2 - 9x + 4)$$

I need to all of these points. It's easy to notice that $~(0,0),~ (1,1),~ (1,-1)~$ are rational points, though I can't find any others and have a feeling that these are the only rational points.

How would I prove this? I am not very familiar with elliptic curves but would like to know how to solve such an equation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42016/algorithms-for-finding-rational-points-on-an-elliptic-curve suggests the general theory may not be up the to task (unless the analytic rank of your curve happens to be one).

Answer (score 4):

These are the only ones. If you define $x=-u/4, y=-v/4$, the curve becomes $v^2=u^3+9u^2+16u$. Using elltors in Pari-gp gives 3 finite torsion points which lead to the points you have found. Using Denis Simon's ellrank code, also in Pari, gives rank $0$ which means there are no other points.

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask if there is a good reference to learn the theory behind rank and torsion points?

Comment: "Rational points on Elliptic Curves" by Joseph Silverman and John Tate is an excellent introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using [sage](https://www.sagemath.org) code. (Sage uses pari/gp for issues related to elliptic curves.) The equation $y^2=-4x^3+9x^2-4x$ can be rewritten in the form
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left(\frac y2\right)^2 &= (-x)^3 + \frac 94(-x)^2 + (-x)\ ,\\
&\qquad\text{ so we are looking for rational points on}
\\
Y^2 &= X^3+\frac 94X^2+X\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve( [ 0, 9/4, 0, 1, 0 ] )
sage: E
Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 9/4*x^2 + x over Rational Field
sage: E.rank()
0
sage: E.torsion_points()
[(-1 : -1/2 : 1), (-1 : 1/2 : 1), (0 : 0 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0)]
```

The values

$(-1,-1/2)$, $(-1,1/2)$, $(0,0)$

obtained for $(X,Y)$ correspond then to the values

$(1,-1)$, $(1,1)$, $(0,0)$

for the variable $(x,y)$ from the OP.

Comment: Thank you!! Can I ask where those numbers came from to define the elliptic curve?

Comment: In sage, one can initialize an elliptic curve in many ways, if already installed ask for the doc-string of `EllipticCurve`, for instance in the sage interpreter (also used above) by typing either `?EllipticCurve` or `EllipticCurve?` or `help(EllipticCurve)`. This gives what i used

    `* "EllipticCurve([a1,a2,a3,a4,a6])"`: Elliptic curve with given $a$-invariants. The invariants are coerced into a common parent. If all are integers, they are coerced into the rational numbers.

but one has also other ways, e.g.

  `* "EllipticCurve([a4,a6])"`: Same as above, but a_1=a_2=a_3=0.

a.s.o.